# How to insert json encoded inputs into foreign related tables

Tags: json, extjs, yii

I am creating functionalities in yii+extjs. My client side is desighned in extjs and server side is in yii framework.
I am having two tables as 
Poll                                   Option
-pollId                              -optionId
-PollQuestion                        -option
                                     -pollId

Now through poll creation form which will be in extjs,Question and its related option gets send to server in json format. So in yii framework,in actionCreate function will get input as-

```
$json='{"pollId":1,"PollQuestion":"Who is the best 
cricketer","option":"ABC","option":"DEF","option":"XYZ"}'
$obj=json_decode($json);
```

During creation of poll,user can enter any number of options.So number of options can be anything.
i am creating above functionality in Pollcontroller. 
So this newly created question gets inserted into Poll table as=

```
$model=new Poll();
           $model->pollId=$obj->pollId;
           $model->PollQuestion=$obj->PollQuestion;
```

Now i want to put all these new options in option table with same pollId. So how to add all these options in option table? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by modifying the JSON so the options are a separate JSON within the pollquestion JSON.
Something like this...

```
$json='{"pollId": 1,"PollQuestion": "Who is the best cricketer",
        "options":{[{"value":"ABC"},{"name": "DEF"},{"name": "XYZ"}]}';
```

That way when you decode it with json_decode you'll get an options array which you can go through and add each of the elements in that array in the options array.

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($obj['options']);$i++){
    //Add to table logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanx sir for your reply... Actually sir i want to put these options in Option table. So sir how to get first option using $json? please help me

Comment: Sir if i am making changes as above,its giving me error for above       for($i=0; $i<sizeof($obj->options);$i++){} loop. Error is Trying to get property of non-object. So what i need to do?

Comment: right... my bad... its $obj['options'] not $obj->options... try that